# If filename matches pattern do something (for-loop, case-statement)

Tags: bash

**The *local* file tree:**

```
/pdf/Insurance.January.2020.pdf
/pdf/Insurance.February.2020.pdf
/pdf/Provider1.March.2020.pdf
/pdf/Provider2.April.2020.pdf
```

**The *remote* file tree:**

```
/invoice/Insurance/2019/January/Insurance.January.2019.pdf
/invoice/Insurance/2020/February/Insurance.February.2020.pdf
/invoice/Provider1/.....
```

**What I want:**
I want to (r)sync my local PDF-files with the remote folders by matching patterns like `Name`, `Year` and maybe `Month`.

**I thought I can solve this with a for-loop and case-statements:**

```
for FILE in ./*.pdf; do
    [[ ! -f "$FILE" ]] && continue # check if $FILE is a file
    FILENAME=${FILE##*/}          # cut only filename
    case "$FILENAME" in
        [Ii]nsurance*)             # matching pattern in filename
            rsync command
            ;;
        Provider1*)
            rsync command
            ;;
        ...
        ...
    esac
done
```

But now I think this is not the fastest way because I've to write a lot of lines to find a match. And I also need to "re-match" `Year` and `Month`.

Has someone another idea? Thanks!

Comment: @alecxs Could you post that as an answer? Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the file names using the `read` command.

```
for FILE in ../pdf/*.pdf; do
    [[ ! -f "$FILE" ]] && continue # check if $FILE is a file
    IFS=. read kind month year ext <<< "${FILE#./pdf/}"

    case "$kind" in
        [Ii]nsurance*)             # matching pattern in filename
            rsync command
            ;;
        Provider1*)
            rsync command
            ;;
        ...
        ...
    esac
done
```

---

1. "${FILE#./pdf/}" expands to the value of `FILE`, minus the leading `./pdf/`
2. `<<<` feeds a string to the standard input of a command.
3. `read` takes a line of input, performs word-splitting based on the first character of the value of `IFS` (here, a `.`), and puts resulting word each variable whose name is passed as an argument.

So if `FILE=./pdf/Insurance.January.2020.pdf`, then

```
IFS=. read kind month year ext <<< "${FILE#./pdf/}"
```

feeds the string `Insurance.Januray.2020.pdf` to `read`, which then performs the assignments

```
kind=Insurance
month=January
year=2020
ext=pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no newlines in filenames.

Big problems are sum of small problems. The small problems are:

1. `find` all files.
2. Transform the list of files.
3. Run rsyncs.

The hardest part is the transformation, applying the list on `rsync`. As usual transforming can be easily done with a regex with `sed` and applying the output on a command can be done with `xargs`.

```
# recreate state
mkdir -p pdf 
touch ./pdf/Insurance.January.2020.pdf
touch ./pdf/Insurance.February.2020.pdf
touch ./pdf/Provider1.March.2020.pdf
touch ./pdf/Provider2.April.2020.pdf

# list all files, ex.
# /pdf/Insurance.January.2020.pdf
# /pdf/Provider2.April.2020.pdf
find "./pdf" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.pdf' |
# tranform the list of srcs\ntarget list
# match /pdf/<anything1>.<anything2>.<anything3>.pdf
# and output the original line
# with another line that has ./invoice/<anything1>/<anything3>/<anything1>.<anything2>.<anything3>.pdf
# the star is taken literally
sed 's@/pdf/\([^\.]*\)\.\([^\.]*\)\.\([^\.]*\)\.pdf$@&\n./invoice/\1/\3/\1.\2.\3.pdf@' |
# run rsync for each two arguments (why rsync?)
xargs -d'\n' -n2 echo rsync
```

[The code outputs on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/CurlyAstonishingHypotenuse#main.sh):

```
rsync ./pdf/Insurance.January.2020.pdf ./invoice/Insurance/2020/Insurance.January.2020.pdf
rsync ./pdf/Insurance.February.2020.pdf ./invoice/Insurance/2020/Insurance.February.2020.pdf
rsync ./pdf/Provider1.March.2020.pdf ./invoice/Provider1/2020/Provider1.March.2020.pdf
rsync ./pdf/Provider2.April.2020.pdf ./invoice/Provider2/2020/Provider2.April.2020.pdf
```

The star is taken literally as a star.

Answer (score 1):

if your file names are always the same pattern you can use `cut` with delimiter `-d` `.` and read the column `-f` into separate variable

you don't even need `case` but if you want to sort month in right order you can do it like that

(run this script inside `pdf/` folder)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for FILE in ./*.pdf; do
    [[ ! -f "$FILE" ]] && continue # check if $FILE is a file
    FILENAME="${FILE##*/}"         # cut only filename

    target="$(echo -e "$FILENAME" | cut -d. -f1)" # matching pattern in filename
    month="$(echo -e "$FILENAME" | cut -d. -f2)"
    year="$(echo -e "$FILENAME" | cut -d. -f3)"

    # delete this if not needed
    case "$month" in
        Jan*)
            month="01.$month"
            ;;
        Feb*)
            month="02.$month"
            ;;
        Mar*)
            month="03.$month"
            ;;
        Apr*)
            month="04.$month"
            ;;
        May*)
            month="05.$month"
            ;;
        Jun*)
            month="06.$month"
            ;;
        Jul*)
            month="07.$month"
            ;;
        Aug*)
            month="08.$month"
            ;;
        Sep*)
            month="09.$month"
            ;;
        Oct*)
            month="10.$month"
            ;;
        Nov*)
            month="11.$month"
            ;;
        Dec*)
            month="12.$month"
            ;;
    esac

    targetpath="../invoice/$target/$year/$month"
    mkdir -p "$targetpath"

    rsync -uxi --noatime "$FILE" "$targetpath"
done

exit 0
```

use the separated variables for folder names.
create the folders with `mkdir -p`

finally call `rsync <SRC> <DEST>` with some options
`-u` only newer files
`-x` stay on filesystem
`-i` display file names
`--noatime` keep last access date
(see `rsync --help` for recommended options)

Comment: sometimes it is good idea not quoting file names like for *'echo -e $FILENAME | cut -d. -f1'* it works better because it removes unwanted linefeeds